# Null Exception Error when checking string for null?

Tags: c#, .net, textbox, split

When running my code i put several string on different lines of the textbox but it breaks saying there is a Null Exception Error on "Items.Add(item)" I am not sure why I am getting
this error because in visual studio the string in the variable item is not null it contains
a return character through so I am not sure if that is an issue.. for example item = "uno\r". Also, Items is a list of strings. Does anyone know why I keep getting this Null Exception?

```
    public List<string> Items;        


    public void getItemsFromTextBox(TextBox textbox)
    {
        string[] lines = textbox.Text.Split('\n');
        foreach (string item in lines)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item))
                Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The `Items` collection is uninitialized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have not initialized your list, it's null!  Add

```
public List<String> Items = new List<String>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You must create instance of `Items` list:

```
public void getItemsFromTextBox(TextBox textbox)
{
    Items = new List<string>();
    string[] lines = textbox.Text.Split('\n');
    foreach (string item in lines)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item))
            Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try with following code.I guess your `Items` list is global one and `shared` list .so better to check that List is initialize or if not then initialize first and do the rest of the thing.

```
    public List<string> Items;        

    public void getItemsFromTextBox(TextBox textbox)
    {
        if(null == Items)
        {
          Items = new List<string>();
        }
        foreach (string item in textbox.Text.Split('\n'))
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item))
                Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You must have create an instance of List Items.

use

```
public List<String> Items = new List<String>();
```

or use the below code

```
public void getItemsFromTextBox(TextBox textbox)
{
    List<string> Items = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbox.Text) ? textbox.Text.Split(new char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList() : new List<string>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have instantiated "Items".